# Does the log determinant loss term mean that there is no need to use weight decay?

Tags: variational-inference

In training affine coupling layers in a normalizing flow, does the log determinant loss term mean that there is no need to use weight decay?

Since the loss term constrains the size of the transformation, does that mean the conditioner also learns simpler functions?

By the log determinant loss term, I am referring to the second term in the flow's likelihood:

$$\log p(x) = \log p(z) + \log \vert \det J\ \vert$$